# Write a dataframe into a JSON array file with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

We have the following code:

```
 val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder
  .master("local")
  .appName("example")
  .getOrCreate()

val data = Seq(
  Row(1, "a","b","c","d"),
  Row(5, "z","b","c","d")

)

val schema = StructType(
  List(
    StructField("id", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("f2", StringType, true),
    StructField("f3", StringType, true),
    StructField("f4", StringType, true),
    StructField("f5", StringType, true)
  )
)

val df1 = sparkSession.createDataFrame(
  sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(data),
  schema
)
```

Goal is write that dataframe in a JSON array :

```
[{"id":1,"f2":"a","f3":"b","f4":"c","f5":"d"},
 {"id":5,"f2":"z","f3":"b","f4":"c","f5":"d"}]
```

So we need this two square brackets but dataframe size is over 50Gb so the solution ***df1.toJSON.collect.mkString("[", "," , "]" )*** is not valid. Are there some way to solve this issue with Spark with a good performance?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try `df1.write().json(path);`? In other words, why are you trying to `collect` dataframe to driver, instead of persisting result to storage like HDFS or S3?

Comment: One big array if I understand?

Comment: 50GB big array in single record? Why is that so? I mean then what's the reason for parallel processing?

Comment: Because this is part from a data migration and we try to simulate that (backend) output, I know that strategy is bad but it is the goal...

Comment: Why am I trying to collect in driver? I said we avoid using collect by using .collect because it is not a valid solution

Comment: Not recommendable to use `.collect`  as the above comments mentioned, more if we are talking about a large `df`, but if that is the requirement I would think in this workaround (if the driver has the specs to handle that amount of data): save your DF without any additional format (just like json). In an additional job, load that but as `string` each row, add a new column as `lit`, then `.groupBy` for that new column and format the string (adding `{}\n`), then collect the final result. Again, is not the best approach, but at least solve that "not expected" requirement.

Comment: maybe in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52971104/how-to-write-dataframe-as-json-array-to-a-file-scala